# Replace part of the value of a json using regex and jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json like bellow:

```
[
  {
    "name": "architecture-design-detailed",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/architecture-design-detailed",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  }
]
```

If name is `architecture-design-detailed`,

- change name to `new_name_here`
- replace last part of rootPath (which is architecture-design-detailed, after the last /) with new_name_here.

So the expected output is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "new_name_here",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/new_name_here",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  }
]
```

What I came up with so far is:

```
jq 'map(if .name == "architecture-design-detailed" then .name = "new_name_here" else . end)'
```

But not understanding how to replace last part of rootPath. I think we have to use `sub` or `gsub`. But not understanding how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split("/")` to convert `rootPath` to an array, then set the last index (`.[-1]`) to `new_name` and then `join("/")` them back together.

We use `|=` inside `map()` to just update those objects found by `select()` and then overwrite `.name` and `rootPath` as needed.

```
map(select(.name == "architecture-design-detailed") 
    |= ( 
        .name = "new_name",
        .rootPath = (.rootPath | split("/") | .[-1] = "new_name" | join("/"))
    ) 
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "new_name",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/new_name",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  }
]
```

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_RWJeCclv2X)

Comment: Well I don't recommend listening to ChatGPT haha. It just a new user, registerd today, with just 2 answers, one on a 12 year old question, and yours... kinda fishy ;) Trying to keep it ChatGPT clean here ;)

Comment: I accepted his answer because he used `sub`. After you mentioned, i removed the `tick`. Could not remove the upvote as i gave it few minutes before (i simultaneously upvoted both answers, yours and his).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal with jq, you indeed need to use the sub function to replace the last part of rootPath when name matches "architecture-design-detailed". Your jq filter needs to be expanded to also conditionally modify rootPath in addition to changing name.

```
map(
  if .name == "architecture-design-detailed" then
    .name = "new_name_here" |
    .rootPath |= sub("/architecture-design-detailed$"; "/new_name_here")
  else
    .
  end
)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "new_name_here",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/new_name_here",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  }
```

]

Comment: Did you write this yourself? Just wondering but If i copy/paste OP's question to ChatGPT, it starts with the exact same text...

Comment: Please comment if the approach won't work. Simple.

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that updates at once the two fields `.name, .rootPath` for selected items matching `.name == $from` by right-trimming by the old name using `rtrimstr($from)`, and then adding the new one with `+ $to`:

```bash
jq --arg from 'architecture-design-detailed' --arg to 'new_name_here' '
  map((select(.name == $from) | .name, .rootPath) |= rtrimstr($from) + $to)
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "new_name_here",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/new_name_here",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "rootPath": "/media/ismail/architecture-design-detailed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/_software/architecture-design-detailed-engineering",
    "paths": [],
    "group": "",
    "enabled": true
  }
]
```